# How to export android studio certificate or keystore from another pc

Tags: android, android-studio, certificate, keystore

I have a problem where I am updating an app in a different pc and I have to insert the new signed apk to release the apk. Is there any option for me to export the keystore from the previous pc to the current pc. Because I've being informed if I want to upload a new apk in play store I have to sign the same certificate and keystore based on the previous version. Is there any way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy .JKS file from previous pc to your current pc

**Step to generate Signed APk with existing keystore**

1.Goto **Build** menu-> select **genarate signed apk** option.

2. Provide Keystore path by choosing **Existing Keystore**.
3. Provide **key Alias**,**Key store password** and **key passowrd** click on **Next** Button
4. If asking for master password provide master password or if you don't know the master password simply reset the password.
5. On next Dialog, select generated apk destination and click on Finish.

Comment: if I have generated a signed apk but it is different than the originally signed apk, is there any way that I can edit it or just follow the step as the above?

Comment: If you generated apk using new keystore then you can not upload it to playstore.

Comment: You need to sign apk using existing keystore.

Comment: so I can't edit the signed apk? or I have to import again the all the file and generate back with the same apk?

Comment: I thing you are missing concept

Comment: You have to import only jks file